# AdvancedFilter Criteriarange from another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, advanced-filter

I am trying to filter for a list of names in column A ("Name"), with the condition that column E ("Primary Category") is not "IT".  I can accomplish the name filtering or the <>IT filtering, but I do not know how to put the two statements together.  Ideally, I would like to have the code look the criteria information up in another closed workbook in dynamic lists.  Here is what I have thus far.

```
   Sub Macro1()
    '
        Range("A1:A196").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A59"), Unique:=False

    End Sub

    Sub Macro3()
    '
        Range("E1:E196").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E2"), Unique:=False

    End Sub
```

Any help in this direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: The criteria range can't be in a closed workbook. Also, as you have multiple rows for the A filter, you'd need to repeat the E filter on each row, or use a formula criterion.

Comment: I tried pulling the criteria for columns A and E using the following, but this doesn't work to get both criteria. to filter.          Range("A1:A196").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:= _
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E59"), Unique:=False

Comment: The filter range needs to be `A1:E196`

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that.  No go.  The two subs work fine on their own range, but when the range is extended from column A to E it only filters on the Name and leaves the "IT"  It must be something else that I'm missing.

Comment: Do you have the right headers in the first row of all columns in the criteria range and did you put the <>IT criteria in every row of that range?

Comment: yes, verbatim for the columns.  I didn't try putting <>IT in every row of the "Primary Category" until now, although that hides all rows except for the header row.

Comment: You have to have it in every row as each row is an OR with every other row; the fields in each row are AND criteria.

Comment: I think,This code should do what you want to do. `Sub Sort_Filter()
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$E$196")
.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*IT*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End With
  With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: Would appreciate feedback on my answer.

Comment: Thank you Rory and Skkakkar for you feedback.  I decided to go a different route with this.  Instead of doing an Advanced filter.  I wrote a simple formula macro that goes out to the closed Workbook using a vlookup formula within the macro.  With the extra column populated, the macro autofilters.  It solved the problem, and I can keep this handy macro in my Personal.xlsb.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering data as per your requirement in the same worksheet, please try this.
Further please see @Rory comment that the criteria range can't be in a closed workbook.

```
Sub Sort_Filter()
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("$A$1:$E$196")
        .AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="<>*IT*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    End With
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: Bwfore program run][image: After program run]

Answer (score 1):

You could open the closed workbook to use it and then close it when you're done.

```
Dim w As Workbook
Dim n As Workbook
Set w = ActiveWorkbook

Workbooks.Open "workbook_with_criteria.xlsx"
Set n = ActiveWorkbook

w.Activate
...
n.Close
```